# problem when using shell_exec() in php code to run python script

Tags: python, php, apache, shell, fedora

I have a php code that run pyhton code but is not working
os: fedora 38
server: localhost using apache

```
$command = 'py testCODES.py';
$output = shell_exec($command.' 2>&1');
```

it gives me this error

```
No executable found for Python
```

any solutions?

i tried solutions these commands:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
sudo chmod +x *.py
```

Comment: None of those solutions have anything to with the error. Evidently python is not installed, or perhaps is not in the PATH for the www user account.

Comment: One way to avoid this issue is to provide full paths: `/usr/bin/python /var/www/[…]/testCODES.py`. You can run `whereis python` to find where is the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when PHP runs `shell_exec(…)`, it doesn't have access to the `$PATH` env var that contain a list of directories that contain the executables.

One way to avoid this issue is to provide full paths so that the shell doesn't have to guess the locations of files:

```
/usr/bin/python /var/www/[…]/testCODES.py
```

You can run `whereis python` to find where is the binary.